# Cant resubmit ajax form after initial submit

Tags: jquery, ajax

Ok so I've tried the below code with and without

```
e.PreventDefault()
```

set on the event and it's still not working.

Here is the form HTML ( I have also tried storing the previous location in the savedLoc hidden input field

```
<form id="cityfilter" method="GET">                 
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-offset-1 col-md-5" >
            <input autocomplete="off" id="location" type="text" class="form-control center-block" placeholder="Filter By Town / City" style="height:40px;margin-bottom:5px;">
            <div id="suggest"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-4" >
        <select class="form-control" style="height:40px;margin-bottom:5px;" id="selectDistance">
        <option disabled>Distance</option>
        <option value="5">5 Miles</option>
        <option value="10">10 Miles</option>
        <option value="15">15 Miles</option>
        <option value="20">20 Miles</option>
        <option value="25">25 Miles</option>
        <option value="35">35 Miles</option>
        <option value="50">50 Miles</option>
        <option value="75">75 Miles</option>
        <option value="100">100 Miles</option>
        <option value="250">250 Miles</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-lg pinkbtn" style="height:40px;color:white" id="addfilter">
        <i class="fa-solid fa-fw fa-lg fa-magnifying-glass"></i>
    </button>
    <input type="hidden" name"savedLoc" id="savedLoc" <?php if(isset($preset)){ echo 'value="'.$preset.'"';}?>>
</form>
```

Here is the AJAX and other jQuery code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#location").keyup(function() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "https://example.com/citylist.php",
            data: 'name=' + $(this).val(),
            beforeSend: function() {
                $("#location").css("background-color", "#FFF 165px");
            },
            success: function(data) {
                $("#suggest").show();
                $("#suggest").html(data);
                $("#location").css("background", "#FFF");
            }
        });
    });
});
var loc = '';
function selectCity(val) {
    $("#location").val(val);
    $("#savedLoc").val(val);
    var loc = $("#location").val();
    $("#suggest").hide();
}
$('#addfilter').click(function()
{
    console.log('Location : '+$("#savedLoc").val());
    var distance = $("#selectDistance").val();
    $('#cityfilter').attr('action', '<?php echo $catbase;?>/'+$("#savedLoc").val()+'/'+distance).submit();
});
```

It works on the first submission & occasionally on the 2nd when you change the distance dropdown, but that's the limit.

I ideally want it so that if the location is already defined it will simply search the location with the updated distance value

Answer (score 0):

`e.preventDefault()` is used to prevent a form from being submitted in the usual way, so the form can be submitted manually with JavaScript or jQuery instead.

From your code, I can't see `e.preventDefault()` being used anywhere. Show us some more code.

**Here is the potential approach**:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#location").keyup(function() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "https://example.com/citylist.php",
            data: 'name=' + $(this).val(),
            beforeSend: function() {
                $("#location").css("background-color", "#FFF 165px");
            },
            success: function(data) {
                $("#suggest").show();
                $("#suggest").html(data);
                $("#location").css("background", "#FFF");
            }
        });
    });

    function selectCity(val) {
        $("#location").val(val);
        $("#savedLoc").val(val);
        $("#suggest").hide();
    }

    $('#addfilter').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var location = $("#savedLoc").val();
        var distance = $("#selectDistance").val();
        var action = '<?php echo $catbase;?>/' + location + '/' + distance;
        $('#cityfilter').attr('action', action);
        console.log('Form action : ' + $('#cityfilter').attr('action'));
        $('#cityfilter').submit();
    });
});
```